# Как сверстать блок картинка+текст справа от нее(на фото)

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Bот кусок html кода — то блоки становятся в ряд, а не друг под другом, то всё исчезнет:

```css
.content{
 display: flex;
 max-width: 1100px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-color: #edeef0;

 font-size: 18px;
 font-style: normal;
 color: #333333;
 line-height: 1.4em;
 letter-spacing: 0em;
}
.content-wrap {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}
.item {
}
.cont-text {

 max-width: 500px;
 margin-left: 40px;
 margin-right: 10px;
}
.cont-text h2{
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 font-size: 23px;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-style: normal;
 color: #333333;
 line-height: 1.4em;
 letter-spacing: 0em;
}
.price {
 margin-top: 30px;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-style: normal;
 color: #333333;
 line-height: 1.37em;
 letter-spacing: 0em;
}

.delivery {
 text-decoration:underline;
 font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
    <seciton class="content">
 <div class="content-wrap">
  <div class="item"><img src="img/icons/item1.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="cont-text">
   <h2>Кабель Lightning/ USB из комплекта iPhone</h2>
   <p>Оригинальный кабель питания Lightning/ USB, который идет в комплекте  с оригинальным iPhone.</p>
   <p class="price">900р</p>
   <a href="#" class="delivery">Купить с доставкой в Череповце</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</seciton>
```

Comment: поставь % соотношение ширины на класс item и content-text

Answer (score 4):

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #edeef0;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #333333;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  letter-spacing: 0em;
}

.content-wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.item {}

.cont-text {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.cont-text h2 {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-size: 23px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #333333;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  letter-spacing: 0em;
}

.price {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #333333;
  line-height: 1.37em;
  letter-spacing: 0em;
}

.delivery {
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<seciton class="content">
  <div class="content-wrap">
    <div class="item"><img src="https://matakov.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/2015-11-15_13-52-10-200x300.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="cont-text">
      <h2>Кабель Lightning/ USB из комплекта iPhone</h2>
      <p>Оригинальный кабель питания Lightning/ USB, который идет в комплекте с оригинальным iPhone.</p>
      <p class="price">900р</p>
      <a href="#" class="delivery">Купить с доставкой в Череповце</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-wrap">
    <div class="item"><img src="https://matakov.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/2015-11-15_13-52-10-200x300.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="cont-text">
      <h2>Кабель Lightning/ USB из комплекта iPhone</h2>
      <p>Оригинальный кабель питания Lightning/ USB, который идет в комплекте с оригинальным iPhone.</p>
      <p class="price">900р</p>
      <a href="#" class="delivery">Купить с доставкой в Череповце</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</seciton>
```

Answer (score 3):

Примерно так

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.item img {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
}

.item p,
.item a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.description {
  width: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px 0 20px 20px;
}

.name {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.surname {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.price {
  line-height: 10px;
}

.btn-color,
.btn-transparent {
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.btn-color {
  background: lightblue;
  color: #fff;
}

.btn-transparent {
  border: 2px solid lightblue;
  color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300" alt="">
  <div class="description">
    <p class="name">Какое то название 1</p>
    <p class="surname">Тут описание того что в названии, и очевидно этот товар очень важный так как его обязательно должны купить</p>
    <p class="price">900</p>
    <a href="#" class="offerta">Купить с доставкой по Москве</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn-color">Добавить в карзину</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn-transparent">Посмотреть прайс</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300/cfc" alt="">
  <div class="description">
    <p class="name">Какое то название 2</p>
    <p class="surname">Тут описание того что в названии, и очевидно этот товар очень важный так как его обязательно должны купить</p>
    <p class="price">900</p>
    <a href="#" class="offerta">Купить с доставкой по Москве</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn-color">Добавить в карзину</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn-transparent">Посмотреть прайс</a>
  </div>
</div>
```